# realloc of two-dim pointer in function in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am using a two-dim pointer to a structure to store a list of addresses I use later.

```
int max=100;
int i=0;
my_structure** addresses=malloc(sizeof(my_struct*)*max);
if (addresses == NULL) //Throw error

do_something_and_fill_list(&i, &max, addresses);
```

And now when I use it in a function, where the list will be filled, after I do a realloc, I get a segmentation fault and I don't know what the problem is:

```
void do_something_and_fill_list(int* i, int* max, my_structure** addresses) {

     (*i)++;
     //do something and add elements
     if (*i==*max) {
       (*max)*=2;
       addresses=realloc(addresses, sizeof(my_struct*)*(*max));
      //so from here it does not work any more
     }
}
```

Comment: Is `my_struct` a typo? Is it `my_structure`?

Comment: yes it is a typo sorry!

Comment: There's no such thing as a "two-dim pointer". Maybe you mean "pointer to a two-dimensional array", but a pointer-to-pointer isn't even that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First Problem:

```
addresses=realloc(addresses, sizeof(my_struct*)*(*max));
```

If it fails to reallocate you'll not notice.

```
my_structure** tmp = realloc(addresses, sizeof(my_struct*)*(*max));
if(!tmp) {
    printf("Unable to allocate more memory");
    exit(1); //Or just return, free addresses or whatever.
}
addresses = tmp;
```

---

### Second problem:

```
void do_something_and_fill_list(int* i, int* max, my_structure** addresses)
```

You're passing a my_structure-ptr-ptr by value, in the function you (may) reallocate this my_structure-ptr-ptr, but from the outside, the new ptr will not be visible. You have to pass it (like every other parameter) by pointer, so you'd pass a my_structure-ptr-ptr-ptr

```
void do_something_and_fill_list(int* i, int* max, my_structure*** addresses)
//Call:
do_something_and_fill_list(&i, &max, &addresses);
//Use:
*addresses = realloc(*addresses, sizeof(my_struct*)*(*max));
```

Comment: I think it would be better to swap problems order, because second problem keeps his program failing and the first one is going to hardly ever occur.

Comment: Ah ok I understand what you mean. So everytime I will possibly modify / reallocate a pointer in a function, to reuse it in other functions I will need to pass a-pointer-to, so one * more than my actual variable has?

Comment: But one more question, shouldn't it be then: `*addresses = realloc(*addresses, sizeof(my_struct*)*(*max));` ??

Comment: @malajedala Oh, you're right. Corrected it. And yes, everytime you modify something in a function and want to see the change on the outside you either need to pass it as a pointer or return it, unless it is a pointer and you only modify the content of that pointer, not the pointer itself. In this case however, you're modifying the pointer itself, so you need to pass the pointer _by pointer_.

Comment: Ok I think it is clear now and also makes a lot of sense, since by reallocating it the address of the pointer may change completely, but sometimes it doesn't but I guess that  is why my bug did not occur before.

Thanks a lot!